# ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] Connection Aborted by remote host

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I want to make new XML feed with prices and SKUs, there are some variants (prevent NULL values), primary we take the value from column 7 from Google sheet, but if we have not product in sheet, then we take price from main XML feed and work with that, everything goes correctly but after some time I get error: ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] Actual connection was ended by remote host (I've tried translate into English language).

I also tried to give some time sleeps but I still getting this error..

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET 
import gspread
import time
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
  
# use creds to create a client to interact with the Google Drive API
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('lorde-mall-911b82a06953.json', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

# Find a workbook by name and open the first sheet
# Make sure you use the right name here.
sheet = client.open("OH-Product-Listings").worksheet('Product_listing_UK')

url = 'https://feed.lordemall.cz/cgi-bin/obchodhracek.xml'
uh = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
  
tree = ET.parse(uh)
  
root = tree.getroot() 


data = ET.Element('SHOP')   

for r in root.findall('SHOPITEM'):
    sku = r.find('PRODUCTNO').text
    try:
        item = sheet.find(sku)
        row = item.row
        time.sleep(2)
        price = sheet.cell(row, 7).value
    except gspread.exceptions.CellNotFound:
        price = r.find('PRICE_VAT').text
    
    
    element2 = ET.SubElement(data, 'SHOPITEM') 
    
    s_elem2_1 = ET.SubElement(element2, 'PRICE_VAT')
    s_elem2_2 = ET.SubElement(element2, 'PRODUCTNO')

    s_elem2_1.text = price
    s_elem2_2.text = sku   
    
    xml_content = ET.tostring(data)

    with open('OH_GBP.xml', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(xml_content)
        f.close()
        time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: you found an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to invalid credentials, please try:

```
import httplib2
if credentials.invalid:
   credentials.refresh(httplib2.Http())
```